# Can I run a bash script in Python and keep any env variables it exports?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

The title pretty much says it all..

Suppose I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# do some magic here, perhaps fetch something with wget, and then:
if [ "$VAR1" = "foo" ]; then
    export CASEVARA=1
fi
export CASEVARB=2

# and potentially many other vars...
```

How can I run this script from python and check what env variables were set. Ideally, I'd like to "reverse-inherit" them into the main environment that is running Python.

So that I can access them with

```
import os

# run the bash script somehow

print os.environ['CASEVARA']
```

Comment: no. variable exports apply only to "child" shells. you can't inherit into "ancestor" shells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certainly! It just requires some hacks:

```
variables = subprocess.Popen(
    ["bash", "-c", "trap 'env' exit; source \"$1\" > /dev/null 2>&1",
       "_", "yourscript"],
    shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

This will run your unmodified script and give you all exported variables in the form `foo=bar`  on different lines.

On supported OS (like GNU) you can `trap 'env -0' exit` to get `\0` separated variables, to support multiline values.

Comment: Wow, this actually works! I've got next to no idea how, but it works :) I mean, `trap`, `"_"`, whaat?

Comment: `trap env exit` runs `env` when bash exits (`source file; env` would work, but fail if the script used `exit`). The first non-option argument (`_` here) becomes `$0` in the script, it's largely arbitrary so I named it `_` as conventionally used for "don't care".

Comment: Thanks. To add to your answer, this is how I parsed them into the Python environment: `os.environ.update(dict([line.split('=') for line in variables.split()]))`

Comment: @frnhr Nice. You may want to use `variables.split("\n")` to not fail for variables with spaces, `line.split('=', 1)` to not fail for variables with equals signs, and filter out entries without `=` since this is merely conventional and not necessarily required.

Comment: Is  it working in python2.7? `os.environ.update(dict([line.split('=') for line in variables.split()]))`

Comment: Very helpful; thank you! In Python3, in order to operate on a basic string, I needed to decode the raw byte string (`variables.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)`).

Answer (score 2):

Use the subprocess module:

- Echo the variables out in your shell script
- Run the bash script from python using [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` set
- Pick them up using `subprocess.communicate()`
- Save them to python variables

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it transparent to the bash script, you could subclass Popen from subprocess and get it to expose the environ of it's process. You could also just grab the contents of it's environ off the disk

```
with open('/proc/%s/environ' % (pid,)) as f:
    env = f.read().replace('\x00', '\n')
```

Would work, but you're racing against the closing and clean up of the process.

Comment: And... that other guy's suggestion is MUCH better :)